# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useMemo')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobx, inversifyjs

I'm trying to use InversifyJS with MobX in my React Native application but I got this error:

> ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useMemo')

I don't use useMemo anywhere. My application is almost empty, I've just installed these packages:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "core-js": "^3.26.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "mobx": "^6.6.2",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "inversify": "5.0.1",
    "inversify-inject-decorators": "3.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

my App.tsx:

```
import "core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"
import React from "react"
import * as eva from "@eva-design/eva"
import { ApplicationProvider, IconRegistry, Button, Layout, Text, Icon } from "@ui-kitten/components"
import { EvaIconsPack } from "@ui-kitten/eva-icons"
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"
import { Provider, useInjection } from "./ioc/ioc.react"
import { container } from "./ioc/ioc"

export default () => (
  <>
    <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      <Provider container={container}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </ApplicationProvider>
  </>
)

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Layout style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button accessoryLeft={<Icon name="google" />}>Sign In</Button>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

This error appears when i want to wrap my app component in Inversify IoC container.

That's how container looks like:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useContext } from "react"
import { Container, interfaces } from "inversify"

const InversifyContext = React.createContext<{ container: Container | null }>({ container: null })

type Props = {
  container: Container
  children: ReactNode
}

export const Provider: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return <InversifyContext.Provider value={{ container: props.container }}>{props.children}</InversifyContext.Provider>
}

export function useInjection<T>(identifier: interfaces.ServiceIdentifier<T>) {
  const { container } = useContext(InversifyContext)
  if (!container) {
    throw new Error()
  }
  return container.get<T>(identifier)
}
```

Comment: Temporarily replaced Inversify with [typescript-ioc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-ioc)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the new Expo SDK 47